# jQuery plugin overwrite all css or only some attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-plugins

I'm creating a simple jQuery plugin for my web app. Right now i'm adding a 'settings' option, which can be used to change the default CSS for the selected elements:

#### Html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var mycss = {tagNormalStyle: {backgroundColor: '#ddd', color:'#222'}};
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#tag1").tagme(mycss);    
        $("#tag2").tagme(null);
    });
</script>
```

#### jQuery plugin

```
$.fn.tagme = function(options) {

// some defaults
var settings = $.extend({
        tagNormalStyle:{
            backgroundColor: 'black',
            color: 'white',
            marginLeft: '5px',
            marginTop: '5px',
            padding: '5px',
            float: 'left',
            borderRadius: '5px'
        },
      //more stuff here...,
       options
      };
}
```

In my code, i'm using something like:

```
if (condition)
    tag.css = settings.tagNormalStyle;
```

The problem is, what if the user **only needs** to change the color, for example?

```
var mycss = {tagNormalStyle: {color:'#222'}};
$("#tag1").tagme(mycss);
```

Now all the defaults are gone for *`tagNormalStyle`*! How can i avoid to 'hard-code' every css property on my settings object? Maybe i could 'merge' the defaults and options objects.
Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pass true as the first parameter to the extend function.
something like:

```
$.extend(true,obj1,obj2)
```

Comment: OUCH easy as a breeze. Thanks!